# Newbie using Google App Engine

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine

I've just started using Google App Engine and I have a few questions about it. I hope you can help me:

1. Once my Java web application is running on Google App Engine. What if one day I decide to run it on my own server. Which programs/services would I need? Is it difficult to configure?
2. I have a Javascript code that I would like to store on Google Application Engine, so that external webpages can run it directly. Is it possible? Otherwise could I deploy a Java application on Google App which returns this Javascript code? How could an external site ask on "execution time" for this code and run it?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) supports Java and allows users to deploy and host their own Google App Engine applications
2. Of course you can, although GAE is not meant to be used as a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).
   Have a look to [Static Files and Resource Files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends on what services you actually use.  Take a look at [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/), it will facilitate running your application on your own servers.  I would also suggest looking at [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) (Python only), to see another software 'stack' providing similar services.
2. See the section on [static files and resources](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! About the static files, it seems that it works when the Javascript file is a part of the web application. But what if ALL I have is the Javascript file, that I want external web developers to include (reference) it on their site code? In this case could I do it with Google App as well? THANKS

Comment: Sure, you could let them use it.  You may also be able to find some CDN that would be better for sharing a static file with people.

Comment: Thank you once again. You have my "up-vote", I don't know who did the other one...